# if else condition for mysql query for more than one row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

For one student if more than two batch id's then `echo "more";` else `echo "one"`. You can see the table has two batch id `4` and `3` assigned to `2`nd student.

```
+---------------+-----------+----------+---------+
| enrollment_id | studentid | courseid | batchid |
+---------------+-----------+----------+---------+
|             1 |         2 |       26 |       4 |
|             2 |         2 |       32 |       3 |
|             3 |         1 |       26 |       2 |
|             4 |         2 |       43 |       1 |
+---------------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Here's the code. **[Edited]**

```
include 'database/db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT enrollments.*, batches.* FROM enrollments 
LEFT JOIN students ON enrollments.studentid=students.student_id 
LEFT JOIN batches ON enrollments.batchid=batches.batch_id";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $batchid = $row['batchid'];
    if ($batchid >= 2) {
        echo "more ";
    }
    else {
        echo "one ";
    }
}

// Output using condition: one
// var_dump($batchid): string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "1"
```

The loop outputs `one` using the condition. How to make this work.

Comment: Your batchid comes from which tbl.

Comment: from `batches` table.

Comment: If you have solve your purpose, using this any answer , then plz vote those answer.Bcoz it helps any other person. Thanks. @beekeeper

Comment: You're `echo`ing based on the ***value*** of a ***single*** `batch_id` and not based on the _COUNT(*) of rows_. You can either modify your query to `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` what you need. Otherwise, you'll have to sort your data by `studentid` and your PHP will have to keep track of the `studentid` and ***count*** as it loops through them.

Comment: Define ***not working***. You haven't shown a ***complete*** [mcve]. So how do you expect anyone _even be capable_ of helping you when you don't provide an explanation of exactly what's wrong?

Comment: fwiw Your `LEFT JOIN` to `students` is pointless because you don't use any data from that table. And as a left join it doesn't affect the `enrollments` rows returned either.

Comment: @CraigYoung updated the question. `LEFT JOIN` use to get student name from the student table, which i will showing in place of student id.

Comment: @Beekeeper That's a crucial detail. Although MySql is lenient about column selection in `group by` queries, other databases are not so. It can have an impact on the answer options. So I suggest you show your intent from the get-go. It's trivial enough to add `students.name` to the SELECT list. _PS: Read my first comment to understand what you've done wrong._

Comment: @CraigYoung Understood. my bad.

Comment: you edited your post to run the query and didn't tell those other guys that you changed your code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Korteby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49595231/224704) works, but is clunky and can be inefficient. This answer provides an improvement.

```
SELECT  s.studentid, s.name,
        sb.BatchCount, /* Can be used for decisions in PHP code */
        /* This uses CASE to differentiate 0 and 1.
           Can replace with IF() function (as per Korteby's answer)
           if the differentiation is not needed. */
        CASE IFNULL(sb.BatchCount, 0)
          WHEN 0 THEN 'zero'
          WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
          ELSE 'more'
        END as BatchNote
FROM    students s
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  studentid, COUNT(DISTINCT batchid) as BatchCount
            FROM    enrollments
            GROUP BY studentid
        ) sb /* Student batches summarises the number of batches per student*/
        ON sb.studentid = s.studentid
```

The PHP code would be trivial to update so that it uses `BatchCount` *instead of* `batchid`.

Comment: Note the only reason this answer joins to the `students` table is because OP clarified that the long-term objective is to include the `name` in the result-set. Otherwise the 3 lines sub-query selecting from `enrollments` is all that's needed to answer the question presented.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution using just **SQL**:

**1- If you need just the studentid**

```
SELECT 
    enrollments.studentid,
    IF(
        (   
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM batches 
            WHERE enrollments.studentid=students.student_id 
            AND enrollments.batchid=batches.batch_id
        )>1
        ,'more'
        ,'just zero or one'
    )
FROM 
    enrollments
GROUP BY
    enrollments.studentid;
```

**2- If you need to get other fields from the student table :**

```
SELECT 
    students.studentid,
    IF(
        (   
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM enrollments, batches 
            WHERE enrollments.studentid=students.student_id 
            AND enrollments.batchid=batches.batch_id
        )>1
        ,'more'
        ,'just zero or one'
    )
FROM 
    students;
```

Comment: This will work but your query is unnecessarily far too complicated and could yield relatively poor performance due to a _correlated subquery_. Much simpler to use: `select studentid, count(*) as BatchCount from enrollments group by studentid` OP could still make the `echo` decision in PHP code. But if still wanting to make the decision in SQL, replace `count(*) as BatchCount` with `IF count(*) > 1 ...`

Comment: You are right i add some improvement to my Query but any way this solution use just SQL.

Comment: It seems you missed the point of my comment because you still have a correlated sub-query. I've provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596132/224704) to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Where `$con` is the connection variable. But it may differ in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

First run the query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```